# Why does expanding the value being integrated give a different value?

Tags: calculus, integration

[My working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2VvX.jpg)

For some reason, when I integrate 1/(4x+2) and 1/2(2x+1), the two results are different:
The integral of 1/(4x+2) is ln(4x+2)/4 while the integral of 1/2(2x+1) is ln(2x+1)/4. Can anyone explain why this is so?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both correct. Note that
\begin{align}
\frac{\ln(4x+2)}4-\frac{\ln(2x+1)}4&=\frac{\ln(4x+2)-\ln(2x+1)}4\\
&=\frac14\ln\left(\frac{4x+2}{2x+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{\ln2}4.
\end{align}
So, the difference between your answers is constant. This shows that both of them are right or that both of them are wrong. And it turns out that both of them are right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I get it now.